# Arrange fields of table in database in alphabetical order

Tags: mysql, field

I have a database "portal" and table "employee" and more than 60 fields in that table not arranged in alphabetical order. I want to arrange the fields name in ascending order from phpmyadmin or by any other means.

I tried  [MySQL sorting table by column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210142/mysql-sorting-table-by-column-names)

```
SELECT column_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_schema = '[portal]'
AND table_name = '[employee]'
ORDER BY column_name
```

...but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you care what order they are in? It is a simple task to order your database column keys in most any language you might be using for the application which is accessing the DB.  If it really does matter for some reason, just reorder the columns in the database via `ALTER TABLE` then you won't have to worry about doing things like referencing the information schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the following:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  table_schema = 'portal'
   AND table_name = 'employee'
ORDER BY column_name
```